# Which authorization grant type should I use?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

In my application, I have many companies accounts.
I'm using [django-oauth-toolkit](https://github.com/jazzband/django-oauth-toolkit) and I gonna to add access to my API by request from a specific company.

I have a few endpoints like:

> `GET /api/users/` - return all company users
>
> `GET /api/documents/` - return all documents owned by users from given company

I wonder which authorization grant type should I use:

Client type: `Confidential`

Authorization grant type options:

- client credentials
- authorization code
- resource owner password-based
- implicit

Can anyone tell me which one type is the best in my case and why?

Comment: See [Oauth simplified](https://aaronparecki.com/oauth-2-simplified/#authorization).

Answer (score 2):

You should use `resource owner password-based` grant:

The resource owner password credentials grant type is suitable in cases where the resource owner has a trust relationship with the client, such as the device operating system or a highly privileged application.

**Flow**:

The client will ask the user for their authorization credentials (ususally a username and password).

The client then sends a POST request with following body parameters to the authorization server:

- `grant_type` with the value password
- `client_id` with the the client’s ID
- `client_secret` with the client’s secret
- `scope` with a space-delimited list of requested scope permissions.
- `username` with the user’s username
- `password` with the user’s password

The authorization server will respond with a `JSON`object containing the following properties:

- `token_type` with the value Bearer
- `expires_in` with an integer representing the TTL of the access token
- `access_token` a JWT signed with the authorization server’s private key
- `refresh_token` an encrypted payload that can be used to refresh the access token when it expires.